# The web server doesnot have the front page server extension installed

Tags: .net

```
the web server doesnot have the front page server extension installed
```

I'm getting this error when trying to run a vs2005 solution. i did install frontserver extension but also gives the same error! can somebody help me with this error.

Comment: Is this too hard http://tinyurl.com/77xob5q to do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be depending on the version you installed. Moreover, the `FrontPage Server` versions are suporting with different `IIS` versions.

Please have a look at this article about [Installing the FrontPage Server Extensions on IIS 7](http://nstalling%20the%20FrontPage%20Server%20Extensions%20on%20IIS%207). You might find the issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: I installed RTR FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions for IIS 7.5, my OS is windows 7 ultimate. but again getting the same error.